# Have tried all solutions here to exit ROM Basic in an old IBM XT - any other suggestions - SYSTEM does not workl

Tags: exit, basic, rom

Any ideas on how to exit the boot up version of basic on an old IBM XT - suggestions here don't work

Comment: How old is your harddisk? Once I reactivated an old PC (not used for 4++ years) .... and the harddisk never booted again.

Answer (score 2):

If your old computer boots-up to ROM BASIC that means that there is no hard drive detected and/or no floppy drive with a boot disk.  There is nothing for "system" to exit to.

You need to either check the connection on the hard disk, if it is indeed an XT model and not just a regular PC, or you need to get a 5.25" PC-DOS or MS-DOS boot disk.

Comment: Drive A: is the 3" Floppy and Drive B: 5.25" Floppy with the hard drive that came with the machine.  I am the original owner and trying to get it ready to sell - I have a 5.25" disk of Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy that I want to check.  Any Idea where to get DOS boot disk.  By the way C: drive light comes on at boot.  Won't boot to the diagnostic 5.25 disk that came originally.

Comment: You need a 3.5" boot floppy then.  It will ONLY boot to drive C:, if it's working, then it will try to boot from drive A:  It will never try to boot from drive B:

Comment: Thanks - any idea where to get one.

Comment: Perhaps ask in the [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/5094/) forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you booted to ROM BASIC, the system works just like an 8-bit BASIC computer. You have no access to the floppy drives or hard drive, and you are not running DOS.

To get to DOS, you need to restart the computer with Control+Alt+Delete - and have a DOS disk inserted.